# Display product reviews in structured data in Big Commerce

Tags: product, bigcommerce, review

I'm looking to display product reviews on product pages in the structured data (head) in Big Commerce. So I am currently doing this via the 'Script Manager'. Here's a little sample of how that looks:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
   {{#if page_type "==" "default"}}
      ...
   {{else if page_type "==" "product"}}
      {
         "@context": "https://schema.org",
         "@graph": [
            {
               "@type": "WebPage"{{#if product.num_reviews ">" 0}},
               "review": [
                  {
                     "@type": "Review",
                     "rating": {{product.rating}}
                  }
               ]
               {{/if}}
            },
            ..
         ]
      }
   {{/if}}
</script>
```

The [documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/storefront/stencil/themes/context/object-reference/schemas#product) doesn't say anything about any ways to get details about reviews other than the two values: `product.num_reviews` & `product.rating` (which appears to be an aggregate of all ratings). Is there any way to get individual reviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reviews property in the product object. Strange, it is not documented.

You could output it into the console to see what it looks like.

[image: BigCommerce reviews in Stencil]

Comment: That's beautiful Tony! Weird about the documentation though<

Comment: Also just to note for people that structured data for 'reviews' (amongst other things) gets picked up within the Markup so there's not always a need to add a custom script